# How to find the integral of $\frac {1}{x^2-x+2}$?

Tags: integration

I am learning homogeneous differential equations, and I tried to answer one of the questions, but I am stuck at integrating the equation above. Are there any easier ways than making the denominator: $$(x-\frac{x}{2})^2+\frac{7}{4}$$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution

Comment: I guess you meant $(x-{\color{red}1/2})^2+7/4$, right?

Comment: Everybody, please! Using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%5Cfrac%7Bdx%7D%7Bx%5E2-x%2B2%7D%5C%20%24&p=1) is not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may just observe that, *by the chain rule*,
$$
\left(\frac1b\arctan \frac{x-a}{b} \right)'_x=\frac1{(x-a)^2+b^2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$x^2-x+2=\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{7}{8}$$ and substitute $$t=x-\frac{1}{2}$$